# Number of Featured Questions Not Corresponding

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I just answered one of the featured (bounty) questions. Checking the other questions, made me realize that only 4 questions were shown:

[image]

After clicking the *complete list* link, it showed me this list:

[image]

I know that one of the questions most probably has entered a grace period, but I would like to see it !!

Is it a bug, caching or status by design?

Comment: My bet would be on caching, but it may be the symptom of another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look earlier when there were 4 questions & now, which has 5 featured questions, and both cases the number's shown correctly. It's probably a caching issue.